# Developing a Counter for Outputting Data Info into a specific range of excel rows & columns?

Tags: python, excel, range, counter

I am a beginner in Python with just basic fundamentals under my belt, ie. loops and modules.  I have some data that I want to automate by exporting it as text into specific Microsoft excel cells.

Specifically, I have 3 folders each with image files in them, a total of 10 image files.  My goal is to make a code that opens up excel and outputs the name of the folder path in each descending row of Column A and the respective image file name in descending rows of column B.

So far, I have defined the folder and path, and have allowed my code to open up Excel and name the sheet and put a title in.  I encountered my problem when trying to individually iterate each folder/file into a new cell. I tried using the range function, but it doesn't work with strings and I feel like a simple counter variable would work, but again, excel column and row names are strings.

Here is my code so far:

```
import win32com.client

import sys, os, string, arcpy

data_folder = "F:\\School\\GEOG_390\\Week11\\data"

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = 1
xlApp.Workbooks.Add()

print(xlApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name)
xlApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value= "Data Files:"


for root, folders, files, in os.walk(data_folder):
for folder in folders:
    workspace = os.path.join(root, folder)
    print( "Processing" + " " + workspace)

    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace

    rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "IMG")

    for raster in rasters:
        arcpy.BuildPyramids_management(raster)
        arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(raster)

        print(raster)


        sheet = xlApp.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        sheet.Range("A2").Value = "Folder:" + folder
        sheet.Range("B2").Value = "Raster:" + raster

        print(sheet.Range("A2").Value)
        print(sheet.Range("B2").Value)
```

I need the code to put folder name 1 in cell A2 and the image file name in B2, and from there on, folder 2 in cell A3 and file 2 in cell B3, all the way until cells A11 and B11.

Comment: I for one have no idea what you are asking or trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you are having trouble figuring out how to increment the names of the cells (for example, "A2" and "B2") each time you process a file.  My apologies if that is not the issue.

(1) Before the first `for` loop, declare a variable `cell_row` that will track the row number where the next pair of cells will be created.  It starts at 2.

```
cell_row = 2
```

(2) Modify the end of your loop as follows:

```
    folder_cell = "A" + str(cell_row)
    raster_cell = "B" + str(cell_row)
    sheet = xlApp.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    sheet.Range(folder_cell).Value = "Folder:" + folder
    sheet.Range(raster_cell).Value = "Raster:" + raster

    print(sheet.Range(folder_cell).Value)
    print(sheet.Range(raster_cell).Value)

    cell_row += 1
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking.  Thank you so much man!  You saved me a headache.  I also appreciate the genuine desire to help, understand, and humility.  I have heard that sometimes newbie posts here can get bombarded with condescension for less of a better or word or just given some huge confusing separate way to approach a problem.  You worked with what I had and made it right.  Is there a way to give a user feedback beyond an up-vote?

Comment: You can also "accept" the answer as being the correct solution to the question asked (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  Thanks for the kind words.  Your remarks about how newbies are sometimes treated are, unfortunately, too often true.

Answer (score 0):

you need to think of it programatically start with a method name

```
def get_xls_range(start,end):
    letter1,num1 = start[0],int(start[1:]) # get the alpha part and the numeric part
    letter2,num2 = end[0],int(end[1:]) # same for end
    #convert the letters to a range
    range_rows = [chr(x) for x in range(ord(letter1),ord(letter2)+1)]
    #convert the numerics to a range
    range_cols = range(num1,num2+1)
    for row in range_rows:
        for col in range_cols:
            yield "%s%s"%(row,col)
```

then all you need to do is interact with your new function

```
  for cell in get_xls_range("A1","B22"):
      print cell
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!